# MySQL InnoDB => composite PK and secondary index

Tags: mysql, innodb

I understand that PK is part of every secondary index in InnoDB, but what about this situation:

I have table structure with two columns

**a,b**

I choose **PK as a+b**

and create **INDEX on b**

Question is, how looks structure on the secondary index ?

Is it stored as

**b a**

or

**b a+b**

---

Or another, more detailed example:

**table: street , city , state , zip , fk_customers**

**PK:  fk_customers + street + city + zip**

**INDEX (city)

INDEX (street)**

Are the secondary indexes stored like this:

**city    fk_customers + street + zip**
**street    fk_customers + city + zip**

or like this:

**city    fk_customers + street + city + zip**
 
**street    fk_customers + street + city + zip**

Comment: unrelated: `fk_customers` is a terrible name for a column. The concept of FK is logical and does not belong to raw data definition. What if the FK is on 2 columns? Would you name them `fk_customers1` and `fk_customers2`? The column names should reflect the functional data they are supposed to be. i.e. `customer_id` or whatever you prefer.

Comment: "What if the FK is on 2 columns?" - I use single (not multi-column) PK-FK table relations so I don't see any problem with it. This format is highly readable for me, I can quicky identify FK occurence when I look at the table definition.

Comment: You missed the point.

Comment: Feel free to explain it in more detail

Comment: I had the same question, thanks for asking it before me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's easy to verify. My gut feeling told the secondary key on `b` would be `b a b`, but InnoDB is smart enough to omit the redundant `b`:

```
mysql> create table t1 (a varchar(32), b varchar(32), primary key (a,b));
mysql> alter table add index(b);
mysql> insert into t1 values('aaa','bbb');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Here's a hexdump of a secondary index page:

```
00004000  07 11 7d 29 00 00 00 04  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |..})............|
00004010  00 00 00 00 ff ee cf d5  45 bf 00 00 00 00 00 00  |........E.......|
00004020  00 00 00 00 09 31 00 02  00 85 80 03 00 00 00 00  |.....1..........|
00004030  00 7f 00 05 00 00 00 01  00 00 00 00 00 01 e0 7e  |...............~|
00004040  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  18 1a 00 00 09 31 00 00  |.............1..|
00004050  00 02 02 72 00 00 09 31  00 00 00 02 01 b2 01 00  |...r...1........|
00004060  02 00 1c 69 6e 66 69 6d  75 6d 00 02 00 0b 00 00  |...infimum......|
00004070  73 75 70 72 65 6d 75 6d  03 03 00 00 10 ff f1 62  |supremum.......b|
00004080  62 62 61 61 61 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |bbaaa...........|
00004090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
```

As you see, column `a` goes right after key column `b`. There is no trailing `b`

Answer (score 2):

The answer above by akuzminsky is correct, but to add a bit more discussion: This is actually discussed in my blog post "[The physical structure of records in InnoDB](http://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/10/the-physical-structure-of-records-in-innodb/)" under the heading "Secondary indexes":

> For example, if a table has a PRIMARY KEY (a, b, c) and a secondary index KEY (a, d), the secondary key in the index will be as expected, (a, d) but the PKVs will contain only (b, c).

You can also confirm this by creating a table and using the `page-dump` or `record-dump` modes along with `--trace` to see the actual bytes encountered when reading the records